# Workflow and Securing? Ruby on Rails API for separated frontend with facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, security, devise, frontend

In standard-current ruby on rails app with standard devise+facebook login i am building API. App must be ready for separated frontend written maybe in node.js or/and angular.js. On RoR side i secured API with standard token access:

```
private

  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    user_email = params[:email].presence
    user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

    # Notice how we use Devise.secure_compare to compare the token
    # in the database with the token given in the params, mitigating
    # timing attacks.    

    if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, params[:token])
      sign_in user, store: false
    end
  end
```

Now the workflow how to do sign-in/up for using facebook or any other omniauth providers. The simpliest idea i had is provide link for frontend like

```
<a href="http://somewhere:8080/users/auth/facebook?target=http://somewhere:80/login.php">Facebook</a>
```

1. Let rails(facebook-omniauth) do the job for facebook authentication and from rails(omiauthcallback controller) respond with redirection to target url(frontend) which we have passed + `&token=abcded` as token for that user.
2. Let frontend store the token and use it in every request when talk to API

The workflow above works, but sure it can be done better. What is best practice?

1. How about to let front-end do the job and authenticate user in facebook? (passport.js) and then resend facebook-info to API and store this info there?
2. Let the backend do the job and authenticate user in facebook (devise omniauth). I can still use sessions `sign_in user, store: true` and no need for tokens? just redirect browser to frontend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would make your app more scalable to have the OmniAuth requests from the client app. This way the server doesn't have to wait on Facebook responses and hold up your rails clusters. If security is an issue for you then you will probably want your api to communicate to the client app via https.

Comment: Yeah, that is solution too. But i don't really like 2 requests shooting to different locations. 1. (Client <-> OmniAuth) 2.(Client <-> API to save the user) In last days i was able to made phonegap client prototype and using rails to do Omiauth job. I will be back here when i really prove it as a stable solution. But i really like to talk about it, if you have more opinions.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me. If you can dream it then you can build it.